# Convert the output of protoc --decode_raw into json

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to convert the message of a protobuf blob into a json, without the corresponding schema. This is the code I'm using but it doesn't get nested objects. Maybe there is a way to convert blobs without the schema? I just need a json. The variable names don't matter to me.

```
message_dict = {}
for line in result.stdout.split("\n"):
    if not line:
        continue
    parts = line.split(": ")
    field_number = parts[0]
    value = parts[1] if len(parts) > 1 else None
    message_dict[field_number] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the `.proto` schema yourself, based on information you learn from `--decode_raw`.

After that it is easy to convert to JSON using the function `google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToJson`.

Comment: the problem is that the output is huge and has several nested messages. I only need one part of that. Is there really no way to convert it raw into a json?

Comment: You can write a schema for just the part you need, and other fields will be ignored automatically.

Answer (score 0):

to whoever it might help out

```
def proto_to_json():
    try:
        # Run the protoc command
        output = subprocess.run(["protoc", "--decode_raw"],
                                stdin=open("tiktok.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8"),
                                capture_output=True,
                                text=True)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        output = subprocess.run(["protoc", "--decode_raw"],
                                stdin=open("tiktok.txt", "r", errors='ignore'),
                                capture_output=True,
                                text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    output_lines = output.stdout.strip().split("\n")
    output_lines = [line.strip() for line in output_lines]

    # Define an empty dictionary to store the output
    output_dict = {}

    # Define a stack to keep track of the nested dictionaries
    stack = [output_dict]

    # Iterate through the lines and add the key-value pairs to the dictionary
    for line in output_lines:
        if ": " in line:
            key, value = line.split(": ", 1)
            stack[-1][key] = value
        elif "{" in line:
            key = line.replace("{", "")
            new_dict = {}
            stack[-1][key] = new_dict
            stack.append(new_dict)
        elif "}" in line:
            stack.pop()

    # Convert the dictionary to a JSON string
    json_output = json.dumps(output_dict, indent=4)

    # Write the JSON string to a file
    with open("file_name", "w") as f:
        f.write(json_output)

    return json_output
```

Comment: This doesn't support repeated fields